# Duplicate table name (csuser.t2) in the FROM clause in inner join

Tags: sql, database, inner-join, informix

Below is the query which is throwing error : as  *Duplicate table name (csuser.t2) in the FROM clause in inner join*

```
SELECT  t1.rxno, 
        t1.txno, 
        t2.create_datetime FROM    mrgrxtxt t1,rx t2
    INNER JOIN      (
        SELECT   rxno, 
               t1. MIN(txno) AS min_txno,
               t2. MAX(create_datetime) AS latest_txno
        FROM    mrgrxtxt t1 , rx t2
        GROUP BY 1
    ) t2 ON t1.rxno = t2.rxno WHERE   t2.min_txno > 8
        AND t2.create_datetime = t2.latest_txno;
```

Can anybody helpout here?? This is informix DB.

Comment: Strongly recommend against trying to mix old style `FROM table1, table2` notations with the explicit join notations `FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON …`.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined two aliases as t2 one for rx and another for the sub query. Try changing the second t2 to something else like t3.

```
SELECT  t1.rxno, 
        t1.txno, 
        t2.create_datetime 
    FROM    mrgrxtxt t1
    JOIN rx t2 ON t1.rxno = t2.rxno
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT rxno, 
               t1. MIN(txno) AS min_txno,
               t2. MAX(create_datetime) AS latest_txno
        FROM mrgrxtxt t1 
        JOIN rx t2 ON t1.rxno = t2.rxno
        GROUP BY 1
    ) t3 ON t1.rxno = t3.rxno 
    WHERE   t3.min_txno > 8 AND t2.create_datetime = t3.latest_txno;
```

Comment: An ON clause has an invalid table reference. is the error now

Comment: Please try the edited one. It could have been because of implicit join.